# How to isert or update an database using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need some help with a piece of script.

The situation is as followed:

I have an database in oracle and i would like to insert bios data using powershell. The problem is that i cant update the database with an if else statment because he keeps saying the if is true.

```
$bios = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class hp_biosSetting 
($bios | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'boot order'})

 $bios4 =echo $bios3.PSComputerName

 $id ="select id FROM TESTAAD"
 $CUR="SELECT id FROM TESTAAD WHERE WAARDE1 = $bios4"

 if ($CUR -ne $id){ 
     $qu= "INSERT INTO TESTAAD  VALUES('$bios4','$waarde6','$waarde5','$waarde4','$waarde3','$waarde2','$waarde1','$id')"
                                        $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
                                        $cmd.CommandText = $qu
                                        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |out-null     


    }  
    else
    {

    echo $bios4
         $qu= "UPDATE TESTAAD SET  waarde2 = '$waarde2' , waarde3 = '$waarde3' , waarde4 = '$waarde5' , waarde5 = 'bla' , waarde6 = '$waarde6' WHERE WAARDE1 = '$bios4'"
                                        $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
                                        $cmd.CommandText = $qu
                                        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |out-null   
                                         echo $bios4


   }












$con.CLose()
```

What I would like to acomplise today is to first insert data with an id and pc name en then update the data

Comment: -1 for code dump. Please read the help about how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within non-updated variable. The `$CUR` is being assigned once, but never updated.

You are comparing if *strings* `select id FROM TESTAAD` and `SELECT id FROM TESTAAD WHERE WAARDE1 = $bios4` are not equal. I'd assume you'd want to compare if the SQL select statement *results* are the same.

It seems like you are missing the actual execution for the SQL statements that `$id` and `$CUR` contain. The SQL queries sure don't do that:

```
$id ="select id FROM TESTAAD" # This is not performing an actual SQL query, only text
$CUR="SELECT id FROM TESTAAD WHERE WAARDE1 = $bios4" # Ditto

if ($CUR -ne $id){ # This is always true, as $id is not equal to $CUR
    $qu= "INSERT INTO TESTAAD  VALUES ('$bios4','$waarde6','$waarde5', `
    '$waarde4','$waarde3','$waarde2','$waarde1','$id')"
    $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText = $qu
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |out-null     
} else {
    echo $bios4
    $qu= "UPDATE TESTAAD SET  waarde2 = '$waarde2' , waarde3 = '$waarde3', `
    waarde4 = '$waarde5' , waarde5 = 'bla' , waarde6 = '$waarde6' WHERE WAARDE1 = '$bios4'"
    $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText = $qu
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |out-null   
    echo $bios4
}
```